# Records that have done more than one transactions in specified days

Tags: sql, excel

I have a dataset with the following fields;

```
1)Customer_ID
2)Customer_Name
3)Transaction_Date
4)Transaction_Amount
```

I need a table with only those customers who have done multiple transactions within 60 days of any previous transaction. I have some basic SQL and Excel concepts. Will appreciate any helpful suggestions. I can use MS Access 2007 or Excel. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I've created an answer for you using SQL Server 2019. The "tricky" part here is using a self join on your date set to compare transaction dates amongst each other. However, in order to make your self join work you'll need to have transaction ID, otherwise you'd end up comparing each transaction record with itself (along with all the others), and there would always be a transaction within 60 days. I manufacture a transaction ID by using the row_number() function in SQL Server. Here's my query:

```
WITH t(t_id, customer_id, customer_name, transaction_date, transaction_amount)
AS(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date) as t_id,
    customer_id,
    customer_name,
    transaction_date,
    transaction_amount
    FROM 
        transactions
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.customer_id, 
    t.customer_name
FROM
    t
JOIN 
    t as tt on 
        t.customer_id = tt.customer_id 
        AND t.t_id <> tt.t_id 
        AND ABS(DATEDIFF(day, t.transaction_date, tt.transaction_date)) <= 60
```

Here's a link to a db-fiddle of my answer.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70afcb2dafd9de4728059a91a43c84d1

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer works for you can you accept it?

Comment: trying to make it work in Access